# DirectAdmin alternative raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, email, raspbian, controlpanel

I got a Raspberry not so long ago, and have some basic Linux knowledge. This Raspberry Pi is host collocated with reverse DNS and its own domain + IP.

Now I want to turn this into a mailserver.

I tried Citadel, but that was not really what I was looking for. I'm looking for a control panel where I can add domain names & email accounts and will also setup the mailserver backend on installation.

First, I was looking at DirectAdmin, but that is not available for the ARM6.

Can anyone suggest me a control panel that isn't to hard to setup, allows easy management of email accounts, is lightweight and will run on the Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but now conceivably, you could install docker and the install directadmin.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51732949/1662973