# Direct Admin + Docker

Tags: docker, admin

I have VPS hosting with Direct Admin. There is Debian Jesse. I can use ssh.

Now I want to install discourse using a docker container. Should I do something more than I can read on tips in the manual?

I mean. I don't know nothing about port. For example Direct Admin using:80 and 443 and 2222. ? Should I set a new "port" for discourse? How to do it?

Comment: Depends on what you want, if you want to use those ports then use those. But you just have to make sure nothing else already on the same port

Answer (score 1):

You can test this command for install `directadmin` via `docker`:

```
docker pull hoolia/directadmin
```

You don't needed to any more act.

More info:
https://hub.docker.com/r/hoolia/directadmin/